# “This comment was edited 2 times”

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, plurals

The first comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25091839/735926) shows it as having been edited “1 time”:

[image]

And the last one “was edited 2 times”:

[image]

I’m not a native speaker, but shouldn’t it be “once” and “twice”?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25091839/735926)
2. Hover the little pen at the end of the first comment and wait a little
3. It should show “this comment was edited 1 time”

I’m using Chrome on [OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X), but this is independent of the browser, because it’s in the markup:

```
$ curl -sL 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/25091839/735926' | grep '[12] times\?'
<span class="edited-yes" title="this comment was edited 1 time"></span>
<span class="edited-yes" title="this comment was edited 1 time"></span>
<span class="edited-yes" title="this comment was edited 2 times"></span>
```

Comment: Hey, perfectly laid out question, and *really not sure* why it was downvoted 11 times =)

Comment: I agree 100%, the sheer amount of down votes seems harsh.

Comment: Poor *thrice*, always overlooked.

Comment: @brasofilo: I guess people disagree it is a bug?

Comment: @faintsignal ... and then *quatrice*, *quintrice*, *sectrice*, *heptrice*, ...?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you don't *have* to use *once* or *twice*. Saying *this has been done 1 time* is fine too, and easier to code up to boot. Sure, it is not *great style*, but it isn't *wrong grammar*! See [Twice vs Two Times](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171833/twice-vs-two-times) on English.SE.

Just be glad the developers dropped the plural `s` from *1 time*, saving you from [Jeff Atwood and his giant S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug)!